# GridView Events Not Working Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, event-handling

I have been trying to hunt down a really frustrating problem. At first it was the RowDataBound event which was not firing, after rewriting the whole gridview now, its the Sorting Event. This time it complains about a handler not being registered for the event. THIS IS A LIE!!!!!!!! 
I have tried many things and I am desperate at this point I really don't know what is going on. Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

```
 protected void ContactsSGV_Sorting2(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        var PLEASE_WORK = true;
    }
<CC:SortableGridView runat="server" ID="ContactsSGV" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="ContactID,ContactType"
AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="ContactsSGV_RowDataBound"
OnPageIndexChanging="ContactsSGV_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="ContactsSGV_Sorting2">
<Columns>
<CC:SortableBoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName"
DefaultImageUrl="~/Images/sortable.png" AscImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-up.png" DescImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-dn.png"
meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldFirstNameResource1" ItemStyle-Width="15%" />
<CC:SortableBoundField DataField="MiddleName" HeaderText="Middle Name" SortExpression="MiddleName"
DefaultImageUrl="~/Images/sortable.png" AscImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-up.png" DescImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-dn.png"
meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldMiddleNameResource1" ItemStyle-Width="15%" />
<CC:SortableBoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName"
DefaultImageUrl="~/Images/sortable.png" AscImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-up.png" DescImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-dn.png"
meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldLastNameResource1" ItemStyle-Width="15%" />
<CC:SortableBoundField DataField="Company" HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="LastName"
DefaultImageUrl="~/Images/sortable.png" AscImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-up.png" DescImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-dn.png"
meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldCompanyResource1" ItemStyle-Width="15%" />
<CC:SortableBoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email"
meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldEmailResource1" DefaultImageUrl="~/Images/sortable.png"
AscImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-up.png" DescImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-dn.png" ItemStyle-Width="16%" />
<CC:SortableBoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Work Phone" SortExpression="Phone"
DefaultImageUrl="~/Images/sortable.png" AscImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-up.png" DescImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-dn.png"
meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldPhoneResource1" ItemStyle-Width="14%" />
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ViewButton" runat="server" Width="25px" Height="30px" ToolTip="View"
CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ContactID") %>' ImageUrl="~/Images/View_24.png"
meta:resourcekey="GVBtnViewResource1" />
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" Width="25px" Height="30px" ToolTip="Edit"
CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit_32x32.png" meta:resourcekey="GVBtnEditResource1" />
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%" />
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</CC:SortableGridView>
 System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
 Message=The GridView 'ContactsSGV' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled.
 Source=System.Web
 ErrorCode=-2147467259
 WebEventCode=0
 StackTrace:
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnSorting(GridViewSortEventArgs e)
 at CustomControls.SortableGridView.OnSorting(GridViewSortEventArgs e) in E:\Local\ProTrackPlus_GroupBy2+\CustomControls\SortableGridView.cs:line 314
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSort(String sortExpression, SortDirection sortDirection)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSort(String sortExpression)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
 InnerException:   

 protected void ContactsSGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
        //THIS ONE WORKS
        var isItWorking = "YES IT IS OMG ";
 }
 protected void ContactsSGV_Sorting2(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
 {
 //THIS IS HELL!
 var PLEASE_WORK = true;
 }
 public class SortableGridView : GridView{
 //STUFF
 }

 protected override void OnSorting(GridViewSortEventArgs e)
 {
 //This is inside my SortableGridView Class.
 //As you can see I am calling the base method and this in fact DOES WORK
 //Is my Handler on a page using this control that does not handle the raised event.
 setSortData(e.SortExpression);
 base.OnSorting(e);
    }
```

[Working Event](http://www.fotoshack.us/foto.php?id=24534WorkingEvent.JPG)
[Not Working](http://www.fotoshack.us/foto.php?id=87632NotWorkingEvent.jpg)

To avoid further attention to the third party control I changed back the gridview to a regular asp one.
This is how the structure looks like now. 
......
Note: Not enough reputation to add link :(

Comment: FYI - a `SortableGridView` is not the same control as the ASP `GridView`.

Comment: NeverMind the SortableGridView. That is a control I created and its entirely replaceable for a regular gridview for this purpose.

Comment: In fact this bug started on a regular asp GridView, I tried to replace it with my own component to see if it made any difference and it didn't.

Comment: have you tried making your event handlers public?

Comment: I just did and no luck. Before you suggest to programatically bind the events. I have actually tried it on the Page load event and on the GridView init event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED IT!!!!!
So it turned out that it was a single line which was crashing the whole thing. There was a ContactsSGV.Dispose() call in the databind wrapper function which was effectively unbinding the handlers. I did not pay attention to it before since I didn't know exactly what it did. I had seen it before on other pages on the project I am working on and it did not cause any trouble. Anyway removing this line made everything work with the regular gridview and my own component.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1336965.aspx/1

Regards 
0x

Answer (score 0):

SortableGridView you are using in your page is third party control and it doesn't belongs to asp control set.It is not same as asp gridview control.There may or maynot the chance for onrowdatabound event.It will depends on control creator.You can see list of classes and methord used in SortableGridView class by right click over 'SortableGridView' class and click 'Go to definition'.

Comment: This control directly inherits from the asp control. The onrowdatabound is working, it was not working before but then it started working and the onSorting handler stopped working. I am 100% is not control related is some sort of corrupted data thing or I don't know I am just speculating.
I made some edits to my code example so that it does not bug you that much that I am using this other control.